# Breeze.js metadata by hand for an Array type

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

Has anyone built metadata by hand for an array type? For example, I just want to bind a

List selectedIds;

to my metadata on the client side. I then want to bind this to an array that corresponds to some checkbox values. Oddly, when I create my new entity the value I am sending for my property is not bound and sent to the server.

var registrationFormModel = ko.observable();
registrationFormModel({ selectedIds: ko.observableArray(), name: ko.observable() });

Later on I set a name and the selectedIds to an array of ints. But it does not map to my entity. Is there a way to have an array type property?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can define a data property which is an array of simple values (e.g., an array of integers). You can also define a property which is an array of "complex types" (as Breeze understands the word).

**These are *array data properties*. They are not *collection navigation properties*.** If you want to use them to acquire and present their implied related entities, you'll have to manage that yourself.

You didn't tell us how you are storing the data on the server. It appears that you are not using a relational database because an RDB doesn't support array properties. A document database (e.g, MongoDb) DOES.

That's OK from a Breeze perspective. But it is important for us to ask and understand what you're doing if we are to provide appropriate help.

Your question reminds me that our documentation doesn't cover array **data** properties. The "zza-node-mongo" sample does illustrate array properties in metadata created by hand.

[Here](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/node/zza-node-mongo/client/app/services/metadata.js#L196) is an example from that metadata definition of an array of integer FK ids which is what you seek, right?

[Here](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/node/zza-node-mongo/client/app/services/metadata.js#L136) is an example of an array of complex types that is *not* a navigation property.

> This metadata sample relies on the "[metadata-helper](http://www.getbreezenow.com/breeze-labs/breezemetadata-helperjs)" in Breeze Labs. That's why you see `hasMany: true` which is an alias for the actual Breeze metadata equivalent, `isScalar: false`.

Comment: How come when I try the second example, the array isn't transformed into an array of complex types? instead what i get is an array of ordinary javascript objects?

Answer (score -1):

Currently I don't think you can create a property that is an array of simple objects.

There are two methods you *could* use though -

1. Pass your collection of Id's down from the server as a complex type with a name/value object -

   `[{id: 1}, {id: 2}]`
2. Use a JsonResultsAdapter to map your simple array to a complex type similar to mentioned above -

   `if (node.IntArray) { 
       var tempArray = [];
       $.each(node.IntArray, function (index, item) {
           tempArray.push({id: item});
       }
       node.IntArray = tempArray;
   }`

Comment: What if the ids are of another type I created in metadata? So for example you have a Registration object and you can sign up for multiple conference options? Each conference has a unique id. How would you solve this? Would I need to configure a navigation property for conferences and have the foreign key on the conference object?

Comment: Presumably, if you want to do it that way.  Another option would be to just leave it as a collection of complex types with a single property Id but when you initialize your entity you could loop through that list and build a collection independent of Breeze's navigation properties.